# iOS games development

Tags: c#, objective-c, ipod

I have just finished studying C with some website, and I covered most of the basic-intermediate things.

Now I want to develop iPod\iPad apps, using Objective-C as I understood it's the best option.
But from reading many guides, I still haven't came across one sure answer - **Can you develop iOS applications using Objective-C on a PC, Windows?** I know you have to pay these 99$ to be allowed to develop and to be given access Apple classes, but it's okay with me.

If you can not do it on windows, what will be the next best option? I know you can create iOS games using Unity and C#, I have it installed but I still didn't find out how to create an iOS project. And I couldn't find a simple guide for iPod apps with unity, that would be nice, too.

If the best option is not unity, what will it be? I have intermediate-high knowledge in .NET (Thats the way it seems in the forums I'm usually at... here I am a simple beginner) and I know C# syntax the best, but I know VB too. And C, and a bit C++.

Thanks :)

Comment: P.S. My iPod\iPad are not jailbroken.

Answer (score 1):

the short answer is no. but there are ways around it if you don't want to put the app in the marketplace

Comment: How can I install it, then? I forgot to mention it before, but my iPod\iPad are not jailbroken...

Comment: iPhone/iPod development should be done on a mac really, anything else is just a hack IMO.

Comment: @harryovers, have you seen Flex 4.5, it doesnt need mac to develop and its certainly not a hack.

Comment: @Akash iPhone support won't be available til later in the year

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend getting a cheap Mac to do your development on. You can get 2007 Intel based Mac Mini on Ebay for ~$200. Then join Apple Developer Program for $99, download XCode4 and you are good to go. Anything else is just a hack like others mentioned on here.

Comment: @harryovers, Flash Builder 4.5 includes full support for building ActionScript® applications for Apple iOS. Flex support is planned to be available later in 2011, from the site, so you can still do ActionScript for iOS

Comment: @Jong, you can dual boot into a Mac on Windows, run Mac on a VM, OR try something like Appcelerator or PhoneGap rather than coding in straight Obj-C.

Comment: @Freedompeace, my friend have tried that, it didn't work well and he had to reformat his computer (He tried with VM).

Comment: @Perceotion, That will be my choice. Just have to convince dad now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can code Objective-C in Windows, however you will not be able to compile. http://kdevelop.org/, http://code.google.com/p/objectiveclipse/ and http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html Dev-C++ are compatible with Objective-C, for example. I haven't had any experience with them, however.

XCode is still the best for this task, and I'm not sure if you would call this being able to "develop iOS applications on Windows", but I tend to code quite a bit in Notepad / GEdit anyway, so the answer is "kind of". You'll need a Mac to go anywhere further than coding though, like being able to debug.

Comment: What is this "XCode", and which language do I use to code? A begginer's guide will be nice :)

Comment: [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html) is Apple's IDE for OSX. If you're serious about writing iOS apps your best best is to get a version of OSX (Apple's operating system) and use XCode to learn both Objective-C and the iOS SDK. There are various ways of emulating OSX on a PC, for example through VMWare, but this has licensing issues. Xcode has plenty of documentation, project templates and support forums so you will have plenty of support.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to generate iOS game with Flex 4.5, which allows you to write and test code on windows and you can package it for iOS. But you have to learn ActionScript and MXML for it.

From Adobe's Website

> Flash Builder 4.5 includes full support for building ActionScript® applications for Apple iOS. Flex support is planned to be available later in 2011

Comment: Come on over smart -1 voter, put some comments if you have guts and little brain !!

Answer (score 1):

The Unity iOS development does not come with the free version of Unity. Instead, you would have to [purchase a separate license](http://unity3d.com/unity/publishing/ios.html) (in addition to the $99 that Apple will charge you to become a developer, I believe.) I myself have never used Unity to develop iOS games, so I don't know how well the process works.

Ideally, however, iOS development really is meant to be done on a Mac. XCode is the primary IDE used for iOS development and it is Mac-only.

Comment: I wanted to pick the ideal way, so I guess ill stick with XCode.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out

- Corono -- http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/
- Unity -- http://unity3d.com/
- Cocoa2d -- http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

Depending on what you are looking, all of them has nice docs that you can go through about their capabilities.